# SQL Case Statement, Alias values with 2 conditions

Tags: sql

Trying to do a case statement with 2 values. I tried following [SQL Case with 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784970/sql-case-with-2-conditions) example but unable to get it.

Logic trying to do:
 where `stack` is in `nodeName` and `overflow` is in `scenarioName`, then replace `nodeName` value `Stack` with `Usethisvalue`, within the `nodeName` column.

My query:

```
SELECT endOfDay as businessDate,
(CASE nodeName,
WHEN nodeName = 'Stack' AND scenarioName = 'Overflow' THEN Usethisvalue
END) as nodeName,
scenarioName, Value
FROM CONTRIBUTION
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like below

```
SELECT endOfDay as businessDate,
CASE WHEN nodeName = 'Stack' AND scenarioName = 'Overflow' THEN 'Usethisvalue'
else nodeName END as nodeName,
scenarioName, Value
FROM CONTRIBUTION
```

Comment: `invalid column name 'UsethisValue'`

Comment: @excelguy check now

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT
>   endOfDay as businessDate, 
>   nodeName, WHEN nodeName = 'Stack' AND scenarioName = 'Overflow' THEN Usethisvalue ELSE 
>   nodeName END as nodeName, 
>   scenarioName, Value 
>   FROM CONTRIBUTION